# Replacing `sbrk` with `mmap`

Tags: linux, posix, mmap, libc, sbrk

I've read that `sbrk` is a deprecated call and one should prefer `mmap` with  `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag. I need one continous (logical) memory block that can grow. However, `mmap` treats first parameter as a hint, so it can make gaps, which is unacceptable in my case. I tried to use `MAP_FIXED` flag (which as documentation states is not recommended) and I can get continuos memory, but after mapping several pages I get strange behaviour of my program: system functions like `printf` and `clock_gettime` begin to fail. I guess the first `mmap` which I call without `MAP_FIXED` returns page that has some mapped pages after it, which contain system data. So what is the right way to use `mmap` instead of `sbrk`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Linux you can use `mmap` with `MAP_NORESERVE` (and possibly `PROT_NONE`) to claim a large chunk of address space without actually allocating any memory.  You map the largest area you could possibly want (and can get), and then remap bits of it with `MAP_FIXED` to actually allocate memory as needed.

Comment: Is this what `malloc` actually does? And what initial amount of memory it uses for MAP_NORESERVE?

Comment: This answer is the same as my answer: if OP can determine the maximum size of the block, then he can `mmap` the entire maximum size. And `MAP_NORESERVE` isn't needed either: if OP doesn't touch the memory, it will not be paged in.

Comment: @EmployedRussian: without MAP_NORESERVE, it will allocate swap space (which may fail), and will definitely allocate PTEs for all pages to refer to that swap space.  With MAP_NORESERVE and PROT_NONE it will just reserve the virtual address range, and won't even allocate PTEs.  So on a 64-bit machine you can reserve a multi-terabyte region quickly, so no other library or whatever will try to use it.

Answer (score -1):

> I've read that sbrk is a deprecated call

Don't believe everything you read, especially if the source is not authoritative.

> I need one continous (logical) memory block that can grow.

In that case, `mmap` is not for you, unless you are willing to declare the maximum size to which that block can grow.

> I tried to use MAP_FIXED flag (which as documentation states is not recommended) and I can get continuos memory, but after mapping several pages I get strange behaviour of my program

With `MMAP_FIXED` you have to be *very* careful: the system will happily map over whatever (if anything) was there before, including `libc` data and code.

Comment: `map sbrk` is not authoritative? "SUSv1, marked LEGACY in SUSv2, removed in POSIX.1-2001."

Comment: @AlexeyAndreev No, "man sbrk" on Linux is not authoritative, and it doesn't claim that the function is deprecated.